# Rotate sprite around pivot with finger drag

Tags: rotation, unity-game-engine, sprite

I am rotating a clock hand around clock center, and I am using:

```
Vector3 dir = mouseClickPos - transform.position;
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y,dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
```

And it is working like a charm. But I need it not to go smooth but to skip around 15 degrees. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
angle=Mathf.Round(angle/15f)*15f
```

(sorry for the wrong math at first, need coffee)

Comment: Nope. It is restricting it to rotate just 15% of full circle.

Comment: One more question, how can I make second object rotate twice slower? For example, when first one makes 360 degrees, second rotates only for 180.

Comment: Do you mean rotating by `angle/2`?

Comment: I am making a clock. And i need, when i move minute hand, to move hour hand too. I have some code, but it is not working well, position of hour hand is reseting at some point.